# Xamarin - How to render list in backend

Tags: xamarin

Currently I have an application which displays a list of items that when selected by a user it opens said item in the default browser on the mobile device they're using.

Currently because the items are hardcoded into the mobile app using the Xamarin platform then a new version of the app is needed to be released/deployed to every device when wanting to update.

I was wondering if anyone could provide me with any documentation/ideas on how I would be able to carry out adding more items to the list (preferably in a better UI than just a standard list) without having to release a new update.

Some ideas which I have thought about:

Using a CMS - to control the links that need to be open

SQL Lite - Create simple db with item name + url then call the url in the table (then somehow when I update the db its pushed into the app)

Using a cloud service such as Azure to do a similar function as above.

This question is vague, but if someone can point me in the correct direction. 
That would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your knowledge, i would go with Azure or Parse Server and deploy the url's there. Each time you open the app it will fetch the links from the remote server. Both Azure and Parse provides caching so you wont incur any network traffic.

It will also depend how frequently you update the links, if you update them often then go setup Azure and Parse. If you rarely update the links then you can setup a local SQLite database and have a way to check from a remote server if there are any new links available, it they are there then you can pull them into your local SQLite database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't think I will look into Parse as they're shutting it down in Jan 2017. This potentially will be a long term use. I will most likely update them at least once a week with new links. You think you could give me a bit of specific details on how I would go about doing this on Azure?

Comment: There's an open source Parse server you can host on your own. They have exactly the same server and dashboard as Parse.com, https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard and https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server. You should accept the answer if you find it helpful